# How can I define the function used in a function template?

Tags: c++

I started to study template in C++ today and I've tried to write a simple code. Then I want to write another function(display) inside the original function(function) using the template parameter(a), but I couldn't find a way to define the "display" function correctly. Is there any solution to pass the compile? Or should I use class template(which I haven't studied yet, but if it's needed, I'll read related materials at once)? By the way, my mother tongue is not English so I used a little translator. Some of my description might seem weird and I'm sorry about that.

I learned that template has its variable scope so I tried to add{}, but it doesn't work. What's more, I don't want to copy the code into the "function" so I have no idea what to do.

```
template <typename T>
void function(T a[],int n)
{
    cout<< "now you are in function." <<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        display(a,i);//Here I have to use "a"
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void display(T a[],int n)
{
    cout << "now you are in display." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[n-i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here's what compiler says:
error: variable or field ‘display’ declared void
void display(T a[],int n)
error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
But I can't use another typename before the "display" function.

Comment: Why don't you have `template <typename T>` before `display` like you do for `function`?

Comment: You cannot directly create functions within functions. But that's the same when you do not use templates.

Comment: And you remember to declare the `display` function before you call it?

Comment: Oh and when you start to learn more about C++ and templates, and if you really want to pass arrays and not only pointers, then a template like `template<typename T, size_t N> void function(T (&a)[N]) { ... }` is probably better. Or better yet, don't use C-style arrays and pointers, use either `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `display` is defined *after* `function`, and therefore cannot be used within `function`; and
2. `display` should be a template function in order to use the typename `T`.

Since `display` is defined after `function`, the compiler will not be able to find `display` when you try to call it within `function`. You can either declare `display` before defining `function`, which basically tells the compiler that the function is defined somewhere else, or you can just move the definition of `display` above `function.

In addition, you need to make `display` a template as well so that it can use the type `T`.

You can fix both problems the easiest way by doing this:

```
template <typename T>
void display(T a[],int n)
{
    // your code here
}

template<typename T>
void function(T a[],int n)
{
    // your code here
}
```

If you really wanted the definition for `display` to come after that of `function`, you could declare `display` before `function` is defined:

```
template<typename T>
void display(T a[], int n);

template<typename T>
void function(T a[], int n)
{
    // your code here
}

template<typename T>
void display(T a[], int n)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Edit: After you update `display` to be a template, you'll need to update your code to call it accordingly:

```
template<typename T>
void function(T a[], int n)
{
    // ... beginning of the function ...
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        display<T>(a, i); // Note the addition of the template parameter
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    // ... rest of the function ...
}
```

Comment: So I should use ' template<typename T> ' whenever I need to use the type 'T', is that right?

Comment: @CursorCC Yes it is. You can name it anything (not just `T`) and get the same effect, but this is up to you.